# What were all the eleven reasons Hannah had for not committing suicide?

Tags: plot-explanation, 13-reasons-why

In *13 Reasons Why* season 2, Olivia shows Clay a list of reasons which Hannah thinks are worth to live for and Clay was mentioned twice and she mentioned her parents there too.

But what were all those eleven reason for not committing suicide?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I rewatched the scene and these are the reasons listed there:

> - **Mom and Dad** They will blame themselves, and it's not their fault.
> - **New York** I could get there someday. If not college, then after college. And maybe I could start over there.
> - **Clay** He will also think it's his fault and it isn't. He'll think he could have saved me. But we can't save people, not that way at least - it's more complicated than that.
> - **Writing** I might - might - write something great one day. Get it published. Even be a writer. Seems unlikey - but possible.
> - **Dad** Loves me without question. Always wants what's best for me. Even though I'm mad at him, it would be unfair to him to leave.
> - **Mom** I don't know if she could live through it. She is always so on edge already. But maybe that's already my fault. I know she loves me--I wish she knew that I knew.
> - **Mom and Dad** Worked hard to give me a better life. Would be letting them down.
> - **Helmet** Is a genuinely good guy. And i genuinely like him. And maybe we're supposed to be together. Don't know. But maybe. If I go, we'll never find out.
> - **Maybe** Someday I could make a difference in someone else's life.
> - **Maybe**  I'll have a kid of my own one day, and maybe she could be that someone else.
> - **Maybe** It's no as bad as I think it is. Maybe it will get better.

[image: First part of the list.]

[image: Second part of the list.]